# jQuery Form, check first four numbers of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is a code checker. Only the first 4 numbers are important, the other numbers can be any number. The form will be used for users to put in productcodes.

The problem is that if the variable changes to say, 5 numbers the variable is false.

See below example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MZfxs/3/

If the user puts in the numbers 3541 the box changes color, but if the user put in the remaining numbers the value is set to false.

Additionally I'm trying to make the box only change color when 13 numbers are inserted AND the first 4 numbers are matching, in that order.

**Solved! 
Working Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/MZfxs/8/

Comment: please explain clear. can't understand.

Comment: @user108 Check the jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need a field value validation and the requirement is the value should start from 4 numbers like `7514` or `9268`. Here you can use a regular expression to validate input value like:

```
// Will work for " 123433 " or "12345634 ", etc.
var value = $(this).val(),
    re = /^\s*(\d{4})(\d+)\s*$/, // better to initialize only once somewhere in parent scope
    matches = re.exec(value),
    expectedCode = 3541,
    expectedLength = 13;
if(!!matches) {
    var code = matches[1]; // first group is exactly first 4 digits
    // in matches[2] you'll find the rest numbers.
    if(value.length == expectedLength && code == expectedCode) {
        // Change the color...
    }
}
```

Also if your requirement is strict to length of 13 than you can modify the regular epression to

```
var re = /^(\d{4})(\d{9})$/;
```

and retrieve first 4 numbers in first group and rest 9 in second group:

```
var matches = re.exec(value);
if(!!matches) {
    var first4Digits = matches[1],
        rest9Digits = matches[2];
    // ...
    // Also in this way you'll not need to check value.length to be 13.
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there should only be numbers, no letters.

Comment: Check my edits for only digits. If you don't want to allow user to enter the space, then remove `\s*` from regular expression.

Comment: Thank you! That works wonders! I've never understood how to setup regex :(

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Really regular expressions is a pretty easy thing - just need to remember common concepts and sometimes google for rules if you forgot something and very soon you'll see that you're thinking in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the string each time on key event fires. You can do this by calling js substring() method and take the first four characters and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
<script>
    $("input").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
     var value2 = $(this).val().substr(0,4);
  if(value2 == 3541){
       $(".square").css("background-color","#D6D6FF");


    }else{
     $(".square").css("background-color","yellow");
    }

    })
</script>
```

Comment: That works nicely! Is there any way to only fire the color change when the variable has 13 characters and the first are matching?

Comment: I answered you above @alessandrominoccheri

Comment: you can change it with 13 with the same function substr in javascript